# Running a jar file in linux server

Tags: linux, printing, jar

Searching a lot in the internet I found that it is possible to run a .jar file in linux server. People said that if it is a simple .jar file (not web application ) then following code will do the task.

```
exec("java -jar jartest.jar", $screen);
```

But when give echo of this output variable $screen it shows only the text "Array" on the screen. I also tried giving echo as below but in that case it shows nothing.

```
echo $screen[0];
```

For your concern for just testing purpose my java code contains only simple printf as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("THIS IS JUST A JAR TEST. AND YEAH JAR IS RUNNING");
}
```

So how can I run such a simple .jar file in linux server and print out the simple output in echo.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

1. move the .jar file to the remote machine, this assume you have access to local terminal, of course you can move the file in any other way

   `scp /path/to/local/file.jar user@remote_ip:~/directory/on/remote/server`
2. open a terminal on remote machine, or use some other tool to access the remote machine

   `ssh user@remote_ip`
3. check what java version is installed there, make sure it's the one you expected

   `java -version`
4. go to the directory you put the .jar file at

   `cd ~/directory/on/remote/server`
5. run the .jar file

   `java -cp file.jar package.and.class.main`

   the main class can sometimes be omitted, depend on how the jar was created and what it consists